# global name self not defined in inherited class

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, self

I have defined an abstract base class in python:

```
class calculator:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        path = './cartesians/'
        onlyFiles = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))]
        for elem in list(onlyFiles):
            test = elem.split('.')[0]
            if test != fileName.split('.')[0]:
                onlyFiles.remove(elem)
        self.onlyFiles = onlyFiles
        self.onlyFiles.sort()

    @abstractmethod
    def optimize(self):
        pass
```

mopac class is inherited from calculator class:

```
from calculator import *

class mopac(calculator):

     def __init__(self, fileName):
        self.test = "test"
        super(mopac, self).__init__(fileName)

    def optimize(calculator):
        print self.test
        for file in self.onlyFiles:
           do stuff
```

and in main.py, I have:

```
from mopac import *

calc = mopac(inFile)
calc.optimize()
```

when I run the code, it tells me:

```
File "main.py", line 50, in main
    calc.optimize()
  File "path/mopac.py", line 24, in optimize
    print self.test
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

I don't understand why it's treating self as a variable/attribute here. Could someone help please? If I remove "print self.test", then it gives me the same error "self is not defined" with self.onlyFiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def optimize(calculator):
        print calculator.test
        for file in calculator.onlyFiles:
           do stuff
```

> The first argument of every class method, including init, is always a reference to the current instance of the class. By convention, this argument is always named self. In the init method, self refers to the newly created object; in other class methods, it refers to the instance whose method was called.

In this case your are renaming the 'self' variable to 'calculator'. Either change it to self or rename self to calculator.

[More info](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

[Other that may help you](http://neopythonic.blogspot.mx/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you should specify `self` as the first formal parameter of a definition. In your code, `calculator` is your first formal parameter, so when it is invoked as an object/instance method, it takes the value of the instance and there is no formal parameter `self` which is accessible (leading to the reported syntax errors):

```
def optimize(self):
    print self.test
    for file in self.onlyFiles:
       do stuff
```

Comment: If I do that it gives an error about the incorrect number of arguments passed to optimize function. Since optimize is defined in the abstract class, I don't need to pass self as an argument.

Comment: That is because you are not passing in an actual parameter for `calculator`, That was a problem in your original code, too, except that `calculator` was being assigned the value that is normally assigned to `self`, so your call to `optimize` didn't trigger an error (except that `self` did not exist, as you expected).

Comment: Since you are not using the formal parameter, `calculator`, and `optimize` doesn't match the base-class declaration, I changed my sample to simply rename `calculator` to `self`.